# KnockoutJs - Observable Binding and Scope

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs

Here are two samples:
Sample 1: http://jsfiddle.net/TheMetalDog/yYAFJ/9/
 
Sample 2: http://jsfiddle.net/TheMetalDog/yYAFJ/11/

In Sample 1, an observable is outside of the viewModel and the chosen title from the select list is attached to the templated items individually as you add items.

```
var selectedTitle = ko.observable();
```

In Sample 2, the observable is inside of the viewModel and all of the items bound to the observable are synchronized and updated together as you add items.

```
viewModel.selectedTitle = ko.observable();
```

Is there a recommended strategy for getting the Sample 1 behavior when working inside of a module environment or more specifically, requirejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout 2.2's new peek function for observables handles this scenario. Here's the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheMetalDog/fD5kF/

The difference is adding `.peek()` here:  `<span data-bind="text: $root.selectedTitle.peek()"></span>`

Comment: Unfortunately that's not really going to help.  It doesn't associate the selected title with the items you have added.  The name is displayed on the view, but you'll loose that all if the view is rendered again.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what your code is trying to do.  It seems like you have two separate view models and you want for them to interact with each other.  If that's the case, you probably want to use [postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox).  It will allow you to keep your view models separate but still allow them to communicate with each other.

So you wanted to take the selected title, and use it when you create a new item or child item in the view model.

Just to get it out of the way, you really need to add a `title` property to your items.  Map the items to another object that has an observable `title`.

```
function Item(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable(data.title); // add a 'title' property to all items
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);

    // map any existing child items to new Items
    self.childItems = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.childitems, function (item) {
        return new Item(item);
    }));
}
```

I think the easiest approach would be to create an "add" and "addChild" topic and have your view model subscribe to it.  When you get updates for that topic, you can add a new item using that title.  Then from your external source, have it publish to the appropriate topic the title you wish to use.

```
function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;

    // ...

    var i = 5;
    function newItem(title) {
        return new Item({
            title: title,
            name: i++,
            childItems: []
        });
    }
    ko.postbox.subscribe('add', function (title) {
        // a title was received for the `add` topic, add it
        self.items.push(newItem(title));
    });
    ko.postbox.subscribe('addChild', function (title) {
        // a title was received for the `addChild` topic, add it
        var firstItem = self.items()[0];
        if (firstItem) {
            firstItem.childItems.push(newItem(title));
        }
    });
}
```

```
// add a new item using the selected title
ko.postbox.publish('add', selectedTitle());

// add a new child item using the selected title
ko.postbox.publish('addChild', selectedTitle());
```

I [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/yYAFJ/14/) to demonstrate what you probably should be doing.

Comment: Thanks Jeff... the issue with your proposed solution is that the behavior is still that of Sample 2 not Sample 1. When you select a title from the dropdown, the dependencies cause every entry to update to the currently selected title instead of keeping the title selected at the time the entry was added. My apologies for not making the question detail as clear as it should have been.

Comment: Oh, so you wanted to use the selected title when you added the items or children?  That's simple then.